How can I help a Ph.D. student who is dissatisfied with my department?
I am supervising a mathematics Ph.D. student who is technically strong, inquisitive, curious, creative, and came in with a very positive attitude. He's been dealing with discouragement, and I'd like to help him.
He expressed frustration with our department, and said that he'd like to tune it out entirely and focus on working with me. He wishes that we had more "fire in the belly", and is frustrated that we're resigned to the realities of being a second-rate department and having to make ends meet. He has been frustrated with the remedial teaching he's been asked to do, he hasn't really made friends with his peers, and he's also upset with the ongoing political situation here in the US.
It has always been my belief that, as it takes a village to raise a child, it takes an entire department to mentor a Ph.D. student. This was certainly true for me; I attribute my success in grad school not only to my advisor, but to many other professors and fellow grad students who helped me along the way.
As such, I'm not sure how effectively I can help him. Especially since I am at best an average "manager" when it comes to time management, planning, etc.
What can I do to help my student achieve his goals?

What are his goals?

Most of what they are frustrated about are not the department per se. Not making friends is a real issue.

Does your college have a strong physics department?

What are the ramifications of "tuning out" the department?  The department will probably not "tune out" the student, even if the student tunes out the department.  FWIW, if the student can find a department not worried about making ends meet, the student should run away from it.

He wants to be a researcher, but I haven't pushed him too much on specifics, and maybe I should. I think our physics department is roughly comparable to ours


he'd like to tune it out entirely and focus on working with me

That seems like a reasonable approach to the overall issue. It's unlikely possible to effect wholesale change in the short period of a PhD career, might as well focus on what's most important and strive to make the next stop (post doc, etc) at a department more fitting.
The rest, though, seems entirely at odds with this approach.

He wishes that we had more "fire in the belly", and is frustrated that we're resigned to the realities of being a second-rate department and having to make ends meet

Well, okay, are we tuning it out or planning to fix everyone else's problems? You can't really control other people's belly fire. A PhD student certainly isn't in a position of leadership that might have some minor influence. If the department is second-rate, well, welcome to the party, Student, this is the department you joined rather than a first-rate one: get used to it. For that matter, even first-rate academic departments are just making ends meet. There's not a lot of glut, any excess there is would be used in any department.

He has been frustrated with the remedial teaching he's been asked to do

Well, given the horrid state of high school education in the US this work needs to be done, and it's work that pays the bills for an academic. Seems like an attitude that needs to change.

he hasn't really made friends with his peers

Well of course not, he thinks he's better than everyone else as they are all second-rate and beneath him.

he's also upset with the ongoing political situation here in the US

That surely doesn't make the student unique, especially in US academia.
So, overall, I think I'd coach the student to indeed focus on their research but if he wants to tune out the rest that means actually tuning it out. I'd recommend you try to help the student take a broader view of the world and be careful of grass-is-greener falsehoods, but that may or may not be productive. I don't think your post meant to be negative at all, but yet I get the impression this person may be a bit on the insufferable side; some people like that grow out of it as they get some humility. Others never will, and you won't be able to help, so don't be too hard on yourself if it doesn't work.

+1 because this is a very useful answer, but I disagree so much that I wrote mine :) (especially about A PhD student certainly isn't in a position of leadership that might have some minor influence)

"If the department is second-rate, well, welcome to the party, Student, this is the department you joined rather than a first-rate one: get used to it." This is such a good sentence that it should be made into a plaque and framed.

Thanks for your answer. In my opinion he's a little cocky and entitled, but nothing extreme, and I was certainly guilty of this myself when I was younger. I've never seen him act mean-spirited. I'm trying to encourage the student to look at the big picture and make the best of the situation he's in, but I haven't managed much success so far.

@academic I'd encourage them that at their next stages, the main things they'll be judged on is research output. Anything they've done before now won't really matter: grades in courses, skill on engineered problems, none matters unless they're able to show something new, so might as well focus on that if they want a place in the next phase of the big picture. When they wander into other complaints, redirect them back to those goals. If they're stubborn about it, I'd try to get them to articulate an actual goal for e.g. the department, something more than being just "better", and work on that.

I'd also coach about realities of the world: being experienced in teaching courses, even remedial ones, is important for getting a job where that's where your salary comes from. There are precious few jobs in math anywhere, and effectively none that let you skip teaching.

Try to harness the "fire" of the student into something productive
Some of these problems are things that can be mitigated and some are beyond the control of you and the student.  Since this student obviously has a lot of "fire" the trick here will be to try to harness that enthusiasm into something productive rather than letting it deteriorate into cynicism and withdrawal.  For this reason, I recommend that you have some discussions with your student on potential avenues by which the student could form opportunities for improving the department in small but meaningful ways.  This might involve uplifting the process for remedial education, adding new seminars or groups for students to meet and discuss ideas, etc.
As part of this approach it will be important to separate out things that are beyond the control of the student.  Here the Serenity Prayer offers good advice: "... grant me the serenity to accept the things I cannot change, the courage to change the things I can, and the wisdom to know the difference".  As part of this, I recommend you teach this student that he will need to learn to put up with some frustrations in any job/career and push ahead with his own work regardless.  It is fine to express frustrations at annoying things beyond your own control, but it is also rational to expect that institutions you work in will not always function as you would like them to and that you will inevitably have to put up with some "bullshit" parts of your job.

From your profile, I'll guess that this is mathematics, which was my field initially. I was in a very large department (~50 professors) and most of them were irrelevant to my needs and goals. My advisor was my main research contact, but there was also a small (3-4 professor and a few students) working/seminar group that met periodically. People could ask and answer questions about their research, though each of the students had a distinct problem to work on.
Outside that group there were a couple of other professors that I could relate to, though they were in different fields than mine. But it wasn't my advisor that set up these contacts. It was nothing more than the fact that I admired them for various reasons including their teaching style. I had some contact with them through required advanced courses leading to comprehensive exams.
A student can't, however, address the issue of thinking the department isn't energetic enough, or is rated too low. Complaining about it won't be helpful, whether it is true or not. Those sorts of things take both time and an infusion of money to solve.
But, I think it would serve everybody well to create such a working seminar that meets, say, weekly. Having an open-door policy within the group, especially for students, might also be workable, and would probably be helpful.

+1 especially for the last paragraph, which if carried out has to potential to solve more than one of the OP-student's issues.

I'm not so sure about the last paragraph. I think you owe it to yourself to put a limit on the time you give to this student's issue. Also, I would advise against an open-door policy to disgruntled PhD students with other advisors -- I suspect almost all PhD students become disgruntled at some stage. The difficult cases can be very difficult. I applaud you for wanting to help, and I think all the answers here are worth exploring. However, I would avoid getting locked into an extra weekly commitment. [I am an ex-academic, and arguably one reason I left is that I did too much firefighting.]

@EdWynn, right. Not always workable.

I was, to some extent, this kind of PhD student. I wanted to push brand new methods into my physics department (more computers, neural networks - it was the early 90s).
I made many friends (usually young physicists) and a few hard enemies. At some point, I realized that either I would go for the dean's chair, or leave academia. I left academia because the neo-medieval system was hard to change and I realized that I could do fantastic things in the industry as well (and be paid 5 times what I would be in academia).
Nice story - but what is the link with you as the supervisor? Well, my supervisor was extraordinary in helping me (often behind my back) to navigate the muddy waters of academia. He "used" (← this is very positive) me to push changes and pour oil where there was too much friction.
He was an average physicist but a truly wonderful supervisor. he did not try to stop me and let me drive my (somehow unusual) PhD. This PhD was really different from others but he said "WoJ, this is your baby and you have to face the music. I think that this is great music but tastes differ".
So what is the conclusion, looking back 25 years? If I were him I would do the same: not interfere but help with my experience and knowledge of people.


It has always been my belief that, as it takes a village to raise a child, it takes an entire department to mentor a Ph.D. student.

However true, it also takes one person to hold responsibility for the final outcome. Otherwise, the result can be death by committee.

What can I do to help my student achieve his goals?

You can help him define targeted specific aims with focused objectives that lead to tangible outcomes for a primary goal of achieving a PhD in mathematics in a defined period of time. Essentially, help him become adept at writing a solid dissertation proposal.
Otherwise, you might act somewhat as a sounding board to his current frustrations if only by noting that each level of responsibility in a career path has its own associated types of frustrations and that sometimes the only lesson is simply in learning which frustrations are battles to fight versus battles to leave well enough alone.
